# run compass watch terminal command upon opening the folder with textmate

Tags: command, textmate, compass-sass

I use textmate for website development and compass to compile css stylesheets. Right now everytime I open up the folder with textmate I have to additionally run a `compass watch /path/to/folder` command. I know textmate is pretty powerfull, but not sure how to make it work so the `compass watch` command is automatically applied to projects you open with textmate (I usually drag the projectfolder on the dock-icon). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. You will need to make a small function in your .bashrc file.

I based the function below off an alias I create for SublimeText2 to make it work like "`mate dir/`" (a feature I missed greatly):

```
#Sublime Text Alias
alias slime='open -a "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app"'
```

So, you don't really want an alias to run two commands, since an alias is...an "alias" for a specific command. However, a function is well suited:

```
#for Textmate
function matew() {
    open -a "/Applications/TextMate.app" $1
    compass watch $1
}
```

I picked "*matew*" - cause it was like mate+watch, but you can call your function whatever you will remember. (e.g `epicPwn()`, etc) Thus, your new function is run as:

```
matew dirName/
```

Note: Just be sure to put the correct path to TextMate. Also, the `compass watch` command will fowl up if you aren't passing a directory, obviously. Similarly if the directory doesn't have a compass project -> `compass watch` will spit back a standard "no project" error (but TM will still open the dir/). e.g.:

```
matew src/
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help.
```

Comment: As an FYI, at least with Sublime Text 2, there is a command line binary called subl. Similar to TextMate's mate.