# After I set Compass to start watching a folder, what key(s) do I then hit to return to the command line?

Tags: compass-sass

After I set Compass to start watching a folder, what key(s) do I then hit to return to the command line? I'm using a Windows PC. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just spawn another command window...this one needs to stay up while the folder is being watched. Here's a good strategy for you :: [run compass watch terminal command upon opening the folder with textmate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105400/run-compass-watch-terminal-command-upon-opening-the-folder-with-textmate?rq=1)